# recreation of absolute value finder not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, absolute-value

I have scripted a code that gives the absolute value of any number here is the code:

```
def absolute(num):
    numb = str(num)
    numb.replace("-","")
    numb = int(numb)
    return numb
```

When used it gives an output of the same integer:

```
>>> absolute(-12)
-12
```

When I did the function step by step I found out that there is the problem in int function where the string "12" gets converted into -12

I know other methods of making this but if you can explain why this happens and that would be better as I can understand what happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you don't assign `.replace` return value back to the variable:

```
def absolute(num):
    numb = str(num)
    numb = numb.replace("-","")
    numb = int(numb)
    return numb
```

In short:

```
def absolute(num):
    return int(str(num).replace('-',''))
```

And one bizarre thing, don't you know about `abs()` LOL?

```
abs(-12)
```

Comment: `numb = numb.replace`is a typo. I'll change it

Comment: well I know about abs and I was just trying to recreate it

Answer (score 0):

```
absolute = lambda x : int(str(x).replace('-',''))
absolute(-5)
```

I shortened the answer someone else gave you. Its a little slow when I time it but I'm sure it should work fine. :)